# How to clean up logs on Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud

I would like to have a log rotation on Magento Cloud, so my logs don't become 5GB files.

**Logs locations**

- /app/okgjweuvmlemc/var/log/
- /app/okgjweuvmlemc/var/report/

From the OS side we have it, but would I be able to set it up on the application side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both can be configured. You can configure how long you need to keep the files.

An example configuration is shown below in your **.magento.app.yaml** file, or if you use Platform.sh you can use the **.platform.app.yaml** file.

```
 logrotate:
      okgjweuvmlemc_logs:
        file: "/mnt/shared/okgjweuvmlemc/var/log/*.log"
        rotate: 365
        period: daily
        set_su: true
        all_hosts: true
```

Comment: in which file we can add above configuration ?

Comment: @Pawan .magento.app.yaml

Comment: thank you @Rafael

Comment: What are "okgjweuvmlemc" and "srxjylamekdzc" strings, what should it be in my case?

Comment: @Jayachandra, your Adobe Commerce project folder (project ID), the folder name is generated by Plataform.sh. You can check the name of your folder by going to /mnt/shared/ and checking which folders you have inside of it.